# Background Image Asset doesn't work in Nuxtjs

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Why does this work in Nuxtjs

```
<img class="img-fluid" src="~assets/images/undraw_work_time_lhoj.svg" alt="">
```

But this doesn't work

```
background-image: url(~assets/images/bg_1.jpg);
```

Comment: where is your css for the background-image ? in component or in a separated file ?
You can put your background in statics to solve this problem